# JSF - Pasar valor de checkbox condicionado para sentencia Update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, método

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo un datatable en Primefaces que me muestra una serie de registros, a los cuales puedo editarlos. Al momento de editarlos, me manda una ventana Modal que me muestra los campos editables entre ellos, un checkbox que se precarga según la condición del campo de la DB.

```
<p:outputLabel value="Contenedor Temperado?" />
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="tempcheckbox" value="#{ordenRetiroBean.ord.es_temperado!=0}"> 
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Ahora, este valor, al momento de actualizar, me manda a mi método en el Bean la lista de campos afectados y también la sesión activa (auditoría).

```
 public void commitEdit() throws SQLException {
    daoOrdenRetiro.editOrdenRetiro(ord, sessionUsuario);
    listadoOrdenes = daoOrdenRetiro.findAll();
}
```

Y mi método DAO lo que tengo es la siguiente manera, que si or.getest_orden == 1, haga esta sentencia, caso contrario haga la otra.

```
public void editOrdenRetiro(OrdenRetiro or,Usuario u) throws SQLException {
    conexion con = new conexion();
    PreparedStatement pst;
    con.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "";
    try {
        if (or.getEs_temperado()==1) {
            query = "update publico.ordenretiro"
                    + "set cia_codigo=?, ids_itinerario=?, lin_codigo=?, booking=?, pto_codigo=?, mov_xcuenta=?, cant_tipocont=?, "
                    + "tipo_carga=?, req_especial=?,"
                    + "inv_seguridad=?, temperatura=?, ventilacion=?, observaciones=?, loc_salida=?, loc_entrada=?, "
                    + "fecha_mod=current_timestamp, usu_mod=?"
                    + "where cod_ordenretiro=?";
        } else {
            query = "update publico.ordenretiro"
                    + "set cia_codigo=?, ids_itinerario=?, lin_codigo=?, booking=?, pto_codigo=?, mov_xcuenta=?, cant_tipocont=?, "
                    + "tipo_carga=?, req_especial=?, "
                    + "inv_seguridad=?, observaciones=?, loc_salida=?, loc_entrada=?, fecha_mod=current_timestamp, usu_mod=?"
                    + "where cod_ordenretiro=?";
        }
        pst = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        if (or.getEs_temperado() == 1) {
            pst.setString(1, or.getCia_codigo());
            pst.setInt(2, or.getIds_itinerario());
            pst.setString(3, or.getLin_codigo());
            pst.setString(4, or.getBooking());
            pst.setString(5, or.getPto_codigo());
            pst.setString(6, or.getMov_xcuenta());
            pst.setString(7, or.getCant_tipocont());
            pst.setString(8, or.getTipo_carga());
            pst.setString(9, or.getReq_especial());
            pst.setString(10, or.getInv_seguridad());
            pst.setString(12, or.getTemperatura());
            pst.setString(13, or.getVentilacion());
            pst.setString(14, or.getObservaciones());
            pst.setInt(15, or.getLoc_salida());
            pst.setInt(16, or.getLoc_entrada());
            pst.setString(17, u.getLogin());
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }
        if (or.getEs_temperado() == 0) {
            pst.setString(1, or.getCia_codigo());
            pst.setInt(2, or.getIds_itinerario());
            pst.setString(3, or.getLin_codigo());
            pst.setString(4, or.getBooking());
            pst.setString(5, or.getPto_codigo());
            pst.setString(6, or.getMov_xcuenta());
            pst.setString(7, or.getCant_tipocont());
            pst.setString(8, or.getTipo_carga());
            pst.setString(9, or.getReq_especial());
            pst.setString(10, or.getInv_seguridad());
            pst.setString(11, or.getObservaciones());
            pst.setInt(12, or.getLoc_salida());
            pst.setInt(13, or.getLoc_entrada());
            pst.setString(14, u.getLogin());
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }

        con.getConnection().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("DAO EDITAR ORDEN RETIRO: " + e.getMessage());
        con.getConnection().rollback();
    } finally {
        con.desconectar();
    }
}
```

Pero me manda el error

> value="#{ordenRetiroBean.ord.es_temperado!=0}": Sitáxis ilegal para Operación de Poner Valor

Comment: Podria mejor crear un metodo que haga la validacion que usted necesita, ya que lo que esta documentado es que el acepta es una propiedad get set asignada, o en su defecto una funcion.

Comment: @Lcop Tienes algún ejemplo para guiarme?

Comment: @Lcop Cree el método para obtener el valor y me funciona, ahora lo que nosé es como pasar ese dato para realizar el update. 

`public boolean temperaturaEdit() {
        boolean check;
        if (ord.getEs_temperado() == 1) {
            check = true;
        } else {
            check = false;
        }
        return check;
    }`

Comment: Explica mejor esta última duda para que te ayudemos

Comment: @pablo Hola pablo, ya lo logré, abajo puse mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo logré. Lo que hice fue crear un boolean en mi Bean.

```
boolean temperado2;
```

La cual, paso a darle valor en el método que se ejecuta cuando presiono Editar, que me abre una ventana modal.

```
public void showEditDialog(OrdenRetiro orde) {
    ord = orde;
    temperado2 = (ord.getEs_temperado() != 0);
}
```

Y en mi xhtml lo que hago es darle el valor del boolean:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Contenedor Temperado?" />
     <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="tempcheckbox" value="#{ordenRetiroBean.temperado2}"> 
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```